# Clicking on the yes checkbox shows 2 form fields, clicking no, keeps those two fields hidden. What do I do?

Tags: html, checkbox, show, hidden

```
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<LABEL FOR="disabilities">5. Do you have any disability which may limit your-----------
<BR>
ability to perform the essential functions of the job
<BR>
for which you are applying?<FONT COLOR="#FF0000"><SUP>*</SUP></FONT>
</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="disabilities"  MAXLENGTH="3" SIZE="6" onFocus="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-23')" onBlur="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-23')" MAXLENGTH="20">
<SPAN ID="msg-23" CLASS="msg" STYLE="visibility:hidden;">Yes or no</SPAN><editcheck="req=Y=Please enter yes or no.">
</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<LABEL FOR="ifyes">If yes, describe----------------------------------------------</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ifyes" MAXLENGTH="50" SIZE="60" onFocus="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-24')" onBlur="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-24')" MAXLENGTH="20">
<SPAN ID="msg-24" CLASS="msg" STYLE="visibility:hidden;">If no, put N/A.</SPAN><editcheck="req=Y=Please enter descriptions of disabilities.">
</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<LABEL FOR="accommodate">What can we do to accommodate you?---------------------</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="accomodate" MAXLENGTH="50" SIZE="60" onFocus="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-25')" onBlur="javascript:toggleMsg('msg-25')" MAXLENGTH="20">
<SPAN ID="msg-25" CLASS="msg" STYLE="visibility:hidden;">If none, type N/A</SPAN><editcheck="req=Y=Please enter accommodations.">
</TD>
</TR>
```

Ignoring the javascript since it doesn't work yet and is part of another question, How do I set this up so I have a checkbox next to disabilities.  Click on yes, it shows "ifyes" and "accommodate" click on no, it doesn't show it.  How do I do that?

Comment: There's a checkbox in that code?

Comment: It's very easy to ignore Javascript which isn't there. It's not clear whether you actually want Javascript, though (I think it will be necessary). And you have spelled `accommodate` wrongly in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put some javascript in to make it work. I have put together a real quick test for you. Feel free to modify it to suit your needs.

JavaScript

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<label for="yesCheck">Yes</label> <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> 
<label for="noCheck">No</label> <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br>
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
    <label for="yes">If yes, explain:</label> 
    <input type='text' id='yes' name='yes'><br>
    <label for="acc">What can we do to accommodate you?</label>  
    <input type='text' id='acc' name='acc'>
</div>
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/

Comment: And if I were to need to have it required when I validate the form?  What should that look like?  The whole form needs help, but I can't type it all in, it's over 5,000 characters too long.

Comment: function validate() { if ((document.getElementById('yesCheck') == false) && (document.getElementById('noCheck') == false)) alert('you need to select one'); }